# Virtual destructors and deleting objects with multiple inheritance... How does it work?

Tags: c++

First, I understand why `virtual` destructors are needed in terms of single inheritance and deleting an object through a base pointer. This is specifically about multiple inheritance and the reason behind *why* this works. This question came up in one of my university classes, and no one (including the professor) was sure why this worked:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    virtual ~A()
    {
        std::cout << "~A" << std::endl;
    }
    int memberA;
};

struct B
{
    virtual ~B()
    {
        std::cout << "~B" << std::endl;
    }
    int memberB;
};

struct AB : public A, public B
{
    virtual ~AB()
    {
        std::cout << "~AB" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    AB* ab1 = new AB();
    AB* ab2 = new AB();

    A* a = ab1;
    B* b = ab2;

    delete a;
    delete b;
}
```

The output for this is:

> `~AB`
>   `~B`
>   `~A`
>   `~AB`
>   `~B`
>   `~A`

How does the compiler know how to call `A`'s and `B`'s destructor when deleting `a` or `b`? Specifically, how is the memory for `AB` laid out (particularly it's virtual function table), such that the `A` and `B` destructors can be called?

My professor was suggesting that memory would be laid out (something) like this:

```
    AB
+---------+              +----+
|  A VFT  | - - - - - -> | ~A |
+---------+              +----+
| memberA |
+---------+              +----+
|  B VFT  | - - - - - -> | ~B |
+---------+              +----+
| memberB |
+---------+

// I have no idea where ~AB would go...
```

We're all curious how these destructors are actually laid out in memory and how calling `delete` on either `a` or `b` results in all the destructors being properly called. It makes sense that deleting a base object works in single inheritance (because there's a single virtual function table to work with), but apparently I'm not understanding things correctly because I can't take my understanding of the single inheritance version and apply it to this multiple inheritance example.

So how does this work?

Comment: Well, the vtable entries would need to point at `~AB`, not `~A` or `~B`...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Ah, that would certainly make more sense.

Comment: Microsoft C++ docs has a nice example of virtual vs non-virtual destruction order https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t4fe76c.aspx#Anchor_2

Comment: It's simple, first `B` then `A` sets the pointer of destructor (in their constructor), but both get overridden by `AB`, so, no matter which you delete, you always call the same destructor!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It works because the standard says that it works.

In practice, the compiler inserts implicit calls to `~A()` and `~B()` into `~AB()`. The mechanism is exactly the same as with single inheritance, except that there are multiple base destructors for the compiler to call.

I think the main source of confusion in your diagram is the multiple separate vtable entries for the virtual destructor. In practice, there will be a single entry that would point to `~A()`, `~B()` and `~AB()` for `A`, `B` and `AB()` respectively.

For example, if I compile your code using `gcc` and examine the assembly, I see the following code in `~AB()`:

```
LEHE0:
        movq    -24(%rbp), %rax
        addq    $16, %rax
        movq    %rax, %rdi
LEHB1:
        call    __ZN1BD2Ev
LEHE1:
        movq    -24(%rbp), %rax
        movq    %rax, %rdi
LEHB2:
        call    __ZN1AD2Ev
```

This calls `~B()` followed by `~A()`.

The virtual tables of the three classes look as follows:

```
; A
__ZTV1A:
        .quad   0
        .quad   __ZTI1A
        .quad   __ZN1AD1Ev
        .quad   __ZN1AD0Ev

; B
__ZTV1B:
        .quad   0
        .quad   __ZTI1B
        .quad   __ZN1BD1Ev
        .quad   __ZN1BD0Ev

; AB
__ZTV2AB:
        .quad   0
        .quad   __ZTI2AB
        .quad   __ZN2ABD1Ev
        .quad   __ZN2ABD0Ev
        .quad   -16
        .quad   __ZTI2AB
        .quad   __ZThn16_N2ABD1Ev
        .quad   __ZThn16_N2ABD0Ev
```

For each class, entry #2 refers to the class's "complete object destructor". For `A`, this points to `~A()` etc.

Answer (score 15):

The vtable entry simply points at the destructor for `AB`. It is just defined that after execution of a destructor, the base class destructors are then called:

> After executing the body of the destructor and destroying any automatic objects allocated within the body, a destructor for class X calls [...] the destructors for `X`’s direct base classes and [...].

So when the compiler sees `delete a;` and then sees that the destructor of `A` is virtual, it looks the destructor up for the dynamic type of `a` (which is `AB`) by using the vtable. This finds `~AB` and executes it. This results in the calling of `~A` and `~B`.

It's not the vtable that says "call `~AB`, then `~A`, then `~B`"; it simply says "call `~AB`" which *involves* calling `~A` and `~B`.

Answer (score 3):

Destructors are called in the order "most derived to most basal", and in reverse order of declaration. So `~AB` is called first, then `~B`, then `~A`, because `AB` is the most derived class.

All destructors are called before the memory is actually freed. Exactly how the virtual function pointers are stored is an implementation detail, and really something you shouldn't be concerned about. A class with multiple inheritance will most likely contain two pointers to the VTABLES of the classes that it derives from, but as long as the compiler and runtime libraries together "work as we expect", it is entirely up to the compiler + runtime libraries to do what they fancy to solve these sort of issues.

Comment: "really something you shouldn't be concerned about" Aw, come on, it's interesting to know! :) (even if it varies from implementation to implementation)

Answer (score 0):

(I know this question is almost two years old but I couldn't resist making a point after I came across it)

Although in the title you use the question word **how**, you also mention **why** in the question post. People have given good technical answers for the how but the why seems to have gone unaddressed.

> This is specifically about multiple inheritance and the reason behind
>   why this works

This is purely guess work but sounds reasonable to me. The easiest way to look at it is that an object using multiple inheritance is composed of a number of base objects. Selectively destructing a base object will leave a *hole* in the composite object and that results in needless complexity when handling methods addressed to those sections of the composite object. Imagine how you would do it if you indeed used composition over multiple inheritance. So it is better to walk the object layout and destroy it as a *whole*.