# Virtual destructors only in selected bases

Tags: c++, c++14

This is a cornercase not covered by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15817941/2567683) (although interesting info is provided therein). My code looks like the following :

```
struct concept {
    virtual ~concept() = default; 
}; 

struct policy {
protected : 
    ~policy() = default; 
}; 

struct implementation final : concept, policy {
};
```

**If I'm only using this hierarchy through pointers to `concept` :**

```
unique_ptr<concept> = make_unique<implementation>();
```

**is the above safe** ?

I believe it is because if someone attempted to delete via a pointer to `policy` the `protected` destructor wouldn't allow it (a trick from `Modern C++ design`) but **does the rest work fine?** (namely when the pointer to concept is deleted are the destructors of the hierarchy guaranteed to be called correctly ? )

Comment: The example would cause less head-scratching if you'd be more explicit and declare `virtual ~implementation() = default;`, too.  But from all I can tell, your code does exactly the same.

Answer (score 5):

Since `~concept()` is virtual, when you `delete` the object via a `concept` pointer, it will call `~implementation()`.

I don't see any reason why the rest will not work like they are supposed to.